# create file with webHdfs

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I would like to create a file to hdfs with webhdfs, I wrote the function below

```
public ResponseEntity createFile(MultipartFile f) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uriPut = new URI(
                webhdfsBaseurl+
                "/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/__MY_PATH/"+f.getName()+ 
                "?op=CREATE" + "&overwrite=true&data=true");
        ResponseEntity e = restTemplate.exchange(uriPut, HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<Resource>(f.getResource()), Map.class);
        URI location = e.getHeaders().getLocation();
        System.out.println(location.toString());

        URI uriPutFnal = new URI(
                location+
                "?op=CREATE" + "&overwrite=true&data=true");
        ResponseEntity eFnal = restTemplate.exchange(uriPutFnal, HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<Resource>(f.getResource()), Map.class);
        
        URI uri = new URI(webhdfsBaseurl+
                "/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/_PATH_"+"?op=LISTSTATUS");
        String test = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println(test);
        
        return eFnal;
    }
```

In the last print I don't see my file...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ResponseEntity createFile(MultipartFile f) throws URISyntaxException, RestClientException, IOException {
    URI uriPut = new URI(webhdfsBaseurl + "/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/dev/ep/flux_entrant/pg6/"
            + f.getOriginalFilename() + "?op=CREATE" + "&overwrite=true&data=true");

    ResponseEntity e = restTemplate.exchange(uriPut, HttpMethod.PUT, null, Map.class);

    if (e.getStatusCode().is3xxRedirection()) {
        URI location = e.getHeaders().getLocation();
        System.out.println(location.toString());
        URI uriPutFnal = new URI(location + "?op=CREATE" + "&overwrite=true&data=true");
        ResponseEntity eFnal = restTemplate.exchange(uriPutFnal, HttpMethod.PUT,
                new HttpEntity<Resource>(f.getResource()), Map.class);

        if (eFnal.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            URI uri = new URI(
                    webhdfsBaseurl + "/gateway/default/webhdfs/v1/dev/ep/flux_entrant/pg6" + "?op=LISTSTATUS");
            String test = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
            System.out.println(test);

            return eFnal;
        }
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();

}
```